# カタカナドメイン（.コム ）を使ってサービスリリースする場合のデメリットについて開発の観点からみてどういうデメリットがありますでしょうか？

Tags: http, network, https

現在知人とwebサービスを作成しております。

近いうちにサービスリリースをするため、ドメインを取得したいと考えております。
（サービス規模は100万UUを目指しております。）

カタカナドメインなんて、考えたこともなかったのですが、
欲しいドメインを取るために、`.コム` ドメインを使用する（.コムしか残ってませんでしたので）か
違うドメイン名を考えて取得するしかありません。

現状では .コム ドメインを取得しようとは思ってますが、それに伴いデメリットを調べております。

調べていると思った程デメリットはなく、こちらぐらいなのかなと思いました。

```
・シェアされるURLがエンコードされる。
・ダサい
・海外展開を目指す場合は不向き（ここは問題ありません。）
```

SEOの観点からもひときわ悪いわけではなさそうなので、気持ちは .コム にうつってます。

しかし、実際運用してみてから、不都合が発生して、ドメイン変更する、といった事態はなるべく避けたいため質問させて頂きました。

是非、ご助言頂けますと幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。

※ また、以下は、本題とそれますが、お名前.comからのメルマガできになった一文がありましたため、
本件に併せて質問させて頂きます。

```
「第三者に同文字列のドメインを取得されないよう別のドメインも取得しておこう」
```

上記ですが、いわゆる example.jp を保持しているとすれば example.com example.co.jp もとっておいた方がいいということみたいですが、ここまで、しっかりと対策されているサービスってそこまで見ない気がします。（一部大手サービス除く）

これぐらいまでやっておいた方が良いものなのでしょうか？
（サービス規模は100万UUのサイトの規模ともあわせて必要かどうかわからず。）

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 「ダサい」というのが極めて強力な敬遠理由になると思います。ネタ目的で取得するなら止めはしませんが、真面目なサービスだとしたら損です。私ならドメイン名を見ただけで恥ずかしくて去ってしまいます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。私も同感ですが、逆にこれがインパクトになる（目を引く）ということを説明され、逆にも捉えられるのではないかとも少しばかり思っております。。。

Comment: インパクトになるのは事実かも知れません。ですがそれはドメイン名を売る側の宣伝文句ではないでしょうか。かつて、ネパールの .np をニッポンと読ませて売ろうとしたところがありましたが、結局定着しませんでした。インパクトを狙っても飽きられますので、やっぱりネタ目的以外には使えないと思います。

Comment: Punycodeになるので色々と不都合があります。例えばAndroidとかでURLを共有してSNSに貼り付けると xn-.....com という謎の文字になります。ドメインのメールアドレスも@以降はPunicode形式になります。それが許容できれば良いんじゃないですかね。「ダサい」云々は個人の主観なんであなたの好きにすればいいと思いますし質問するようなことじゃないと感じます。

Comment: コムドメインということは、Verisignですね。http://verisign.コム/ にはアクセスしてみましたか？